# How to get a CSV file from an external URL using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, csv, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to get a CSV file from the following URL (http://s3.amazonaws.com/misc-ww/data.csv) and parse the data in this file on the fly. What I am trying to achieve by parsing the data in the file is important, feel free to look at the file if you wish to make suggestions on it; *however my current problem lies in getting the data in the file itself*. When using either XMLHttpRequest, or an Ajax call, or a JSONP call; the response is always returning with error. Meaning that the file for some reason cannot be accessed.

After researching for a few hours, I am sure this has got to do with some kind of security restriction (cross domain request), sadly I have not come any closer to understanding how to get around it. For sample purposes I have created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AGE/7jvwqkfn/) highlighting my attempt at retrieving the CSV file via an AJAX JSONP call (code seen below).

HTML

```
<button>Click me to get the CSV File</button>
```

Javascript

```
function getCSV() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://s3.amazonaws.com/misc-ww/data.csv",
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {
            alert("Success: " + data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrow){
            alert("Error: " + jqXHR['responseText']);
        }
    });
}
```

$('button').click(function() {
    getCSV();
});

My main goal is to be able to achieve this via Javascript alone, however I do welcome any answers that involve jQuery. I am aware of javascript frameworks that could allow this to work for me, but in my case I need to code without them.

Comment: look up "cross domain request". what you want is impossible without extra measures.

Comment: CORS reffer http://enable-cors.org/server.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant really bypass CORS with JSONP calls if server doesn't support them. Its more the way **server** don't have to set "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" header. Instead server can send respond inside callback function to bypass straight JSON response. So your problem is that you .csv file is not wrapped inside a callback function.

So server which supports JSONP and gets ?callback=cbFunc it will print:

```
cbFunc('here is my file content')
```

Now you are asking .csv file and server is sending it without wrapping it to callback function. That's why you end up with security restriction.

Long story short: You cant get file via AJAX JSONP like that because **s3.amazonaws.com does not support JSONP**.

here is nice explanation about JSON and JSONP: http://json-jsonp-tutorial.craic.com/index.html

Sorry about repeating myself.

Comment: You could actually make your own server side script to get the file. In PHP use file_get_contents('http://s3.amazonaws.com/misc-ww/data.csv') to get data and then print it for your JSONP call in right format.